# Ionic 3 How to change the radio icon of ion-radio color when checked to another one?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I need to change the color of checked radio icon.

I changed the existing styles of `ion-radio` to:

```
ion-radio.radio.radio-checked, ion-radio.radio.radio-md
{
   background-color: white;
}
```

But it was not the one required.

Then changed to:

```
ion-radio.radio.radio-checked, ion-radio.radio.radio-md
{
   color: white;
}
```

But still the same.

I need to change the blue colour of the checked variable to white.

Then I tried to change the `radio-inner` and `radio-icon` to:

```
ion-radio.radio.radio-checked, ion-radio.radio.radio-md
, ion-radio.radio.radio-icon, ion-radio.radio-inner{
  background-color: white;
}
```

But it didn't changed.

From the documentation, we should change the following css variable to another color:

```
--color-checked
```

But still the same. Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-checkbox-radio-up2nxr).

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this css code:

```
.radio-md .radio-checked,
.radio-md-primary .radio-checked {
  border-color: #fff;
}
.radio-md .radio-inner,
.radio-md-primary .radio-inner {
   background-color: #fff;
}
.item-md .radio-md {
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

And Remove this code:

```
ion-radio.radio.radio-checked, ion-radio.radio.radio-md
{
   background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Add this CSS:
.item-md .radio-md {
   background-color: transparent;
}